# Ruby: how to crop and resize image from center

Tags: ruby, image-processing, imagemagick, paperclip

I am trying to resize an image and crop it from the center. i.e. if the resolution is 1024x512 and I want to resize by 256x256 I would resize the smallest side to 256 and maintain aspect ratio, i.e. resize the image to 512x256 and then I want to crop the 256x256 square from the centre.

I have seen solutions with paperclip but only for Rails, but I'm not sure how to do this in just a regular script.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use,

```
Magick::ImageList.crop!(CenterGravity,256,256)
```

[More options](http://www.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/image1.html#crop)